# PHPMailer devuele error 550 al enviar a gmail o hotmail

Tags: php, phpmailer, mailer

tengo un enviador de correos para enviar presupuestos, todo funcionaba bien hasta hace un timpo atrás, sigue enviando bien los mail pero cuando envia a gmail o hotmail devuelve el siguiente error.

Error SMTP: Datos no aceptados.Error del servidor SMTP: DATA END command failed Detail: This message was classified as SPAM and may not be delivered SMTP code: 550

desde el webmail del proveedor del servicio o desde windows funciona todo correctamente y el proveedor del servicio me dice que ni la ip del servidor ni el dominio están en listas negras.

Alguien sabe de como solucionarlo? Gracias Adrian.

**Agregué al código el mensaje que envío, puede haber algo ahí?** (*22/03/2022*)

Código

```
    $mensaje = '
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <center>
            <img src="https://viagrafica.com.ar/svg/logo.svg"><br><br>
            <span style="font-size:14pt; color:black"> Hola ' . $cliente . '</span><br><br>
            <span style="font-size:14pt; color:grey"><b>Te acercamos el presupuesto solicitado a nuestra empresa.<br>Tu número de presupuesto es el ' . $nro_presupuesto . '.<br>Puedes descargarlo haciendo click en el vínculo a continuación.</b></span><br><br>
            <a href="https://viagrafica.com.ar/pre_genera.php?p=' . base64_encode($hash1) . '">
            <span style="font-size:14pt; color:red">Descargá tu presupuesto</span></a>
            <span style="font-size:10pt; color:grey">
            <p>Este mensaje fue originado automáticamente</p>
            <p>El presente mail no podría haber sido enviado sin que Ud. nos proporcionase<br>su dirección de correo electrónico. Queda bajo su exclusiva responsabilidad<br>informar a VIAGRAFICA de cualquier cambio o modificación que dicha dirección sufriese<br>
            El contenido del presente mensaje es privado, confidencial y exclusivo<br>para su destinatario, pudiendo contener información protegida por normas legales<br>y de secreto profesional. Bajo ninguna circunstancia, su contenido puede<br>ser transmitido o relevado a terceros ni divulgado en forma alguna.<br>VIAGRAFICA no se responsabilizará por los daños o perjuicios<br>derivados del incumplimiento de lo aquí establecido</p></span>
            <span style="font-size:10pt; color:grey"><p>design & development by <b>grafikós</b>&nbsp;arte en diseño<br>© (' . copyright(2020) . ') <b>Adrian Bergonzi</b></p></span>
            </center>
        </body>
    </html>
    ';

$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();

$mail->setLanguage('es', '../PHPmailer/language/');
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                            
$mail->isSMTP(); 
$mail->Host       = 'servermail.viagrafica.com.ar';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Username   = 'correo@viagrafica.com.ar';
$mail->Password   = '*******';
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
$mail->Port       = 587;

$mailCliente = trim($row_leo_cliente['email']);
$mail->setFrom('correo@viagrafica.com.ar', 'ViaGrafica');
$mail->addAddress(($mailCliente), $cliente);

$mail->addReplyTo('correo@viagrafica.com.ar', 'ViaGrafica');

$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'VIAGRAFICA - Presupuesto Nº ' . $nro_presupuesto;
$mail->Body    = $mensaje;
$mail->AltBody = $mensaje;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    $bd_error = 'Error del Mailer: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE presupuesto SET enviado = %s, m_enviado = 1 WHERE id = %s", GetSQLValueString($dia_hoy, "date"), GetSQLValueString($_POST['presupuesto'], "int"));
    $bd_1->query($updateSQL);
    $db_error = 0;
}
```

Debug

```
2022-03-15 12:07:19 Connection: opening to mail.viagrafica.com.ar:25, timeout=300, options=array()
2022-03-15 12:07:19 Connection: opened
2022-03-15 12:07:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-blue115.dnsmisitio.net ESMTP Exim 4.94.2 #2 Tue, 15 Mar 2022 09:07:19 -0300 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO viagrafica.com.ar
2022-03-15 12:07:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-blue115.dnsmisitio.net Hello viagrafica.com.ar [186.64.119.95]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-PIPE_CONNECT250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS250 HELP
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2022-03-15 12:07:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO viagrafica.com.ar
2022-03-15 12:07:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-blue115.dnsmisitio.net Hello viagrafica.com.ar [186.64.119.95]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-PIPE_CONNECT250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250 HELP
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2022-03-15 12:07:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2022-03-15 12:07:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2022-03-15 12:07:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 Authentication succeeded
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<correo@viagrafica.com.ar>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<correo@gmail.com>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Accepted
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
2022-03-15 12:07:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Tue, 15 Mar 2022 09:07:19 -0300
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: =?UTF-8?Q?Adrian_Bergonzi_-_Grafik=C3=B3s_arte_en_dise=C3=B1o?= <correo@gmail.com>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: ViaGrafica <correo@viagrafica.com.ar>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: Reply-To: ViaGrafica <correo@viagrafica.com.ar>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?VIAGRAFICA_-_Presupuesto_N=C2=BA_00000014?=
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <GNumFQ9P9jeAdmB03C6RUEoeBMYyDnWp5sKLKOg@viagrafica.com.ar>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: boundary="b1_GNumFQ9P9jeAdmB03C6RUEoeBMYyDnWp5sKLKOg"
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_GNumFQ9P9jeAdmB03C6RUEoeBMYyDnWp5sKLKOg
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: <html>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: <head>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: </head>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: <body>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: <center>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: <img src="https://viagrafica.com.ar/svg/logotipo_mail.svg"><br><br>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: <span style="font-size:14pt; color:black"> Hola Adrian Bergonzi - Grafikós arte en diseño</span><br><br>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: <span style="font-size:14pt; color:grey"><b>Te reenviamos tu presupuesto Nº 00000014.<br>Puedes descargarlo haciendo click en el vínculo a continuación.</b></span><br><br>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: <a href="https://viagrafica.com.ar/admin/presupuesto.php?p=codigo">
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: <span style="font-size:14pt; color:red">Descargá tu presupuesto</span></a>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: <span style="font-size:10pt; color:grey">
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: <p>El presente mail no podría haber sido enviado sin que Ud. nos proporcionase<br>su dirección de correo electrónico. Queda bajo su exclusiva responsabilidad<br>informar a VIAGRAFICA de cualquier cambio o modificación que dicha dirección sufriese<br>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: El contenido del presente mensaje es privado, confidencial y exclusivo<br>para su destinatario, pudiendo contener información protegida por normas legales<br>y de secreto profesional. Bajo ninguna circunstancia, su contenido puede<br>ser transmitido o relevado a terceros ni divulgado en forma alguna.<br>VIAGRAFICA no se responsabilizará por los daños o perjuicios<br>derivados del incumplimiento de lo aquí establecido</p></span>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: <span style="font-size:10pt; color:grey"><p>design & development by <b>grafikós</b>&nbsp;arte en diseño<br>© (2020/2022) <b>Adrian Bergonzi</b></p></span>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: </center>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: </body>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: </html>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_GNumFQ9P9jeAdmB03C6RUEoeBMYyDnWp5sKLKOg
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: <html>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: <head>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: </head>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: <body>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: <center>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: <img src="https://viagrafica.com.ar/svg/logotipo_mail.svg"><br><br>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: <span style="font-size:14pt; color:black"> Hola Adrian Bergonzi - Grafikós arte en diseño</span><br><br>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: <span style="font-size:14pt; color:grey"><b>Te reenviamos tu presupuesto Nº 00000014.<br>Puedes descargarlo haciendo click en el vínculo a continuación.</b></span><br><br>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: <a href="https://viagrafica.com.ar/admin/presupuesto.php?p=codigo">
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: <span style="font-size:14pt; color:red">Descargá tu presupuesto</span></a>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: <span style="font-size:10pt; color:grey">
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: <p>El presente mail no podría haber sido enviado sin que Ud. nos proporcionase<br>su dirección de correo electrónico. Queda bajo su exclusiva responsabilidad<br>informar a VIAGRAFICA de cualquier cambio o modificación que dicha dirección sufriese<br>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: El contenido del presente mensaje es privado, confidencial y exclusivo<br>para su destinatario, pudiendo contener información protegida por normas legales<br>y de secreto profesional. Bajo ninguna circunstancia, su contenido puede<br>ser transmitido o relevado a terceros ni divulgado en forma alguna.<br>VIAGRAFICA no se responsabilizará por los daños o perjuicios<br>derivados del incumplimiento de lo aquí establecido</p></span>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: <span style="font-size:10pt; color:grey"><p>design & development by <b>grafikós</b>&nbsp;arte en diseño<br>© (2020/2022) <b>Adrian Bergonzi</b></p></span>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: </center>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: </body>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: </html>
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_GNumFQ9P9jeAdmB03C6RUEoeBMYyDnWp5sKLKOg--
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2022-03-15 12:07:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
2022-03-15 12:07:24 SERVER -> CLIENT: 550 This message was classified as SPAM and may not be delivered
2022-03-15 12:07:24 SMTP ERROR: DATA END command failed: 550 This message was classified as SPAM and may not be delivered
Error SMTP: Datos no aceptados.
Error del Mailer: Error SMTP: Datos no aceptados.Error del servidor SMTP: DATA END command failed Detail: This message was classified as SPAM and may not be delivered SMTP code: 5502022-03-15 12:07:24 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2022-03-15 12:07:24 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 blue115.dnsmisitio.net closing connection
2022-03-15 12:07:24 Connection: closed
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código que usas para enviar correos. La mayoría de las veces, los correos enviados usando `sendmail()` en lugar de SMTP son los que se rechazan por ser considerados SPAM.

Comment: Prueba actualizar a la última versión de [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/releases). Puede ser que estos servicios de correos hayan actualizado algo en sus protocolos.

Comment: Ayer actualicé a la última versión de PHPMAILER pero continua el error.

Comment: ¡Estás compartiendo datos sensibles (IP y URL de tu sitio)! Anonimiza lo más posible los datos que tengas que exponer. Revisa [esta sección de la ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question), en donde se menciona: _si has publicado algo supersensible (...), edítalo y luego repórtalo para pedir a los moderadores que lo **redacten** del historial de revisiones._ ("Redactar", explicándolo mal y rápido, es poder editar el historial de ediciones para eliminar la información sensible).

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de que el SMTP de tu proveedor está reportado por spam. Alguna otra cuenta puede que haya hecho uso indebido y quedó marcado allá

Comment: Encontré un error en MultiRBL:
 IP addresses with multiple PTR records may fail some SMTP compliance checks. 

Podría ser esto que etá perjudinado a PHPMAILER?

Comment: Pues yo le pregunto a Google y dice que [tu dominio sólo tiene un registro PTR](https://dns.google/query?name=viagrafica.com.ar&rr_type=A&ecs=&show_dnssec=true). Ahora., si miramos tu IP, [hay dos dominios asociados](https://dns.google/query?name=186.64.119.95&rr_type=A&ecs=&show_dnssec=true) pero pinta que uno es del sitio HTTP y otro del subdominio para correo... dudo mucho que sea eso

Comment: Prueba estas dos cosas: 1) Evita que el Subject tenga mayúsculas sostenidas. Evita usar carácteres especiales en el Subject. 2) Asegúrate de que el usuario en el from, el usuario que se autentica al SMTP y el usuario en el replyto Sean El Mismo Usuario. Usa una variable para asignarle a mail->From, mail->ReplyTo y mail->Username el mismo contenido.

Comment: Prueba 3) Intenta evitar que se quejen por PHPMailer: `$mail->XMailer = ' ';`

Comment: Lo de gmail es porque alguien (o varios) han reportado tus correos como spam varias veces, y ya no te deja pasar pues reconoce tu dominio y seguramente tu rango de ips (veo que usas 3 para el SPF).  Lo de hotmail es más normal, siempre bloquean a saco y hay que hacer muchas cosas para conseguir pasar sus filtros. No tienes una solución a nivel de código, sino a nivel de gestión con cada uno de ellos, suscribiendote a sus herramientas webmaster e intentando que te dejen pasar dándoles muchos datos sensibles para que sepan quien eres. Eso si, si envias spam olvidate.

Comment: @masterguru Los bloqueos por 550 no siempre se deben a blacklisting. Hay muchas razones por las que un correo se puede considerar spam sin necesidad de tener su IP en lista negra. Por otra parte, el proveedor debería garantizar algún método de envío distinto a un simple relay, que garantice que si el correo llega escribiendo desde su interfaz web, también llegue desde un servidor autenticado correctamente con las mismas credenciales.

Comment: @AlexanderVega Comparto lo del 550, motivos puede haber muchos, pero revisando su IP, sus registros DNS, sus RLBS, su PTR, su SPF, su DMARC, me ha parecido lo más lógico, pero tampoco es que me hubiera fijado detenidamente en toda la info de la pregunta, je.  En cuanto a lo del proveedor, dudo que tenga culpa ninguna, no sabemos a que se refiere con lo del webmail, si lo manda desde la propia cuenta y desde la misma IP, o una de las otras dos IP que tiene en su SPF, la reputacion de esas IPs es buena, vamos, que descartando todo lo que tiene bien solo me quedaba eso por decir :-)

Comment: Podrias aclararme si hay informacion para redactar? no termino de entender si hay informacion sensible.. por favor, dejame un comentario y lo hablamos en un chat

Comment: @gbianchi nada, creo que no se ven las password.... error mio... sera que pone emails reales y algun scrapper los puede pillar, asi como el nombre de dominio

Comment: Solo como un comentario más... ¿os habeis fijado en el nombre de dominio?  **ViaGrafica** ... si lo dividimos un poquito nos aparece la palabra **VIAGRA**...ejem... no digo que sea eso, pues por webmail dice que le funciona, pero diria que eso suma puntos en cualquier analisis de spam que tengan como filtro... ya es mala suerte, je

Comment: Prueba esto: http://isnotspam.com/ al menos verás la puntuación de spamassassin sobre tu texto, etc... No digo que lo esten usando en gmail o hotmail, pero da una idea de lo que puede estar fallando en tu contenido.

Comment: Gracias @masterguru, cambié todo lo que decía ViaGrafica en el texto por Via Grafica y funciona nuevamente.

Comment: Además le tuve que quitar el
    img src="https://midominio.com/svg/logotipo_mail.svg">
porque sino no lo envía.

Comment: Bueno, me alegro que te haya servido, pero no cantes victoria... algunos filtros antispam "aprenden" sobre la marcha (los bayesianos), y lo que hoy puede pasar mañana pueden decirte que no, porque si juntan "via gra" ya estamos otra vez bloqueados, o si empiezan a reportar tus emails, en fin, por mil motivos... nunca des por sentado que ya siempre te funcionará pues nunca se sabe que se les puede pasar por la cabeza a los sysadmins. Tengo bastante experiencia en ese campo gestionando servidores de correo y decenas de miles de cuentas de correo, y he vivido de todo, y no hay una solución total.

Comment: Es que haste fines de Enero estaba todo bien, y en Marzo comenzó a fallar, lo mismo que el svg que enviaba de cabecera com img scr ya no me lo acepta. Y jamás envié masivos son presupuestos individuales, El sistema completo comienzan a usarlo el mes que viene, espero no comience de nuevo a fallar por otro bloqueo. Igual gracias nuevamente @masterguru